# Unit Test Array Push

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I'm creating unit tests for a component and a line where i make a push for an array is not covered.
The method I created loops through values and checked if they are undefined or not. If the value exists the value is pushed to the array - if not, it is not added.
This is the method:

```
  valueList : string [] = [];
  value : string;
showValues(){
    for(let i = 20; i<=40; i++){
        this.value = this.parser.parseFromString(
        this.content.transform( '.content'+i),
        'text/html',
      ).body.innerHTML;
      if(this.value != 'undefined'){
        this.valueList.push(this.value); //not covered in branch coverage
      }
    }
```

Here's what I tried but it fetches a "Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given" error

```
 component.showValues();
    component.valueList.push(component.values);
    if(component.values != 'undefined'){
      expect(component.valueList.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the word undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
showValues(){
    for(let i = 20; i<=40; i++){
        this.value = this.parser.parseFromString(
        this.content.transform( '.content'+i),
        'text/html',
      ).body.innerHTML;
      if(this.value != undefined){ // note the removal of single quotes
        this.valueList.push(this.value); 
      }
    }
```

unit test:

```
component.content = "<p>abc</p>"; // define the content that will come back with a value from your parseFromString code
component.showValues();
expect(component.valueList.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```